# HTML and CSS are not linking together

Tags: html, css

For whatever reason, my the HTML and CSS for my page will not link. CSS is in the same directory. I have ran the page through a validator and no issues have come up, so there is no reason this shouldn't work? I'm not stupid, never had this problem before either, so I'm quite confused. It just has no effect.

https://jsfiddle.net/4ocpjL1v/

```css
maintext {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    text-align: center;
}

logo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UnleashedMC | Join Us!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="howtojoin.css" />
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Main content area -->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logomedium.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="maintext">
            <p>Join us at ulmc.net</p>
            <p>Don't know how to join? Read below!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Recommend you find a simple tutorial on using the Developer Tools in the Chrome browser.  Takes 15 minutes to understand how to verify CSS attributes are attached to your html elements.  Will save you lots of time in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use `#` for IDs (or `.` for classes) before the name.

```
#maintext {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Actually, apparently not? It works on JSFiddle, but will not on a live site. Take a look? http://ulmc.jok.re/pages/howtojoin.html

Comment: That's because you're using `class` in your HTML but `#` in your CSS.  Change the `#`s in your CSS to `.` and it should work (I prefer not to use IDs)

Comment: Fixed that too, whoops. Still a no go. Using ID with a # doesn't work either.

Comment: It seems to still be that way on the site - are you testing locally?  I was able to get it to work.

Comment: Nope, not local. CSS is now using . s and HTML is using classes instead. It simply isn't taking effect.

Comment: And now I tried the exact code from JSFiddle using id and #, it still just won't work. I don't understand.

Comment: Last comment, sorry for spamming: I got it to work, sorta, but it's stuck again. I think it may be an issue with the server, we'll see.

Comment: Yep, it was a caching issue. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>UnleashedMC | Join Us!</title>
 <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald:400,700,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="howtojoin.css" />

</head>
<body>
   <!-- Main content area -->
    <div id="container">
        <div id="logo">
            <img src="images/logomedium.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="maintext">
            <p>Join us at ulmc.net</p>
            <p>Don't know how to join? Read below!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>



#maintext {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    font-size: 36px;
    text-align: center;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Oswald';
    text-align: center;
}

#logo {
    text-align: center;
}
```

this will work for sure....u have put font after css, it should be before css.
See Live https://jsfiddle.net/subodh_saraswat/4ocpjL1v/1/

Comment: That's actually not the problem, as the ordering really doesn't matter. The actual problem was that I mixed up classes and divs on accident without realizing, and then there was a caching issue causing the page to not update at all, which has now been resolved. Thanks for your help, though.